# Why am I getting weird values when I copy integers into a new dynamic array?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

I wrote a function in C to copy all prime numbers from one int array into a new dynamic array that will be of the same size.

**This is the function:**

```
int *cpy(int arr[], int size){
    int *newArr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (isPrime(arr[i])) {
            *(arr + i) = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

**This is the driver code**

```
int arr[SIZE] = { 129, 73, 87, 2, 923, 6743, 983, 23 };
int *newArr = cpy(arr, SIZE);
printf("Question 4: ");
printIntArr(newArr);
free(newArr);
```

Note `SIZE` is a macro defined as 20 in a header file I'm using to store all prototypes/macros

For some reason I get the following output:

```
Question 4: 12261328 12255424 285212761 39925 33619971
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm relatively new to C, so I'm sorry for silly errors

EDIT: I tried first comment solution but I got:

```
Question 4: 129 6684864 87 33150 923
```

Comment: `*(arr + i) = arr[i];` -> `*(newArr + i) = arr[i];`

Comment: I tried that, but I got `Question 4: 129 6684864 87 33150 923`

Comment: You need a second index to track adding entries into  `newArr`. And you need to tell the caller how many entries were added.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean. `void printIntArr(int* arr)` uses `SIZE` which is defined as 8 in my header file. It knows the size of the array received but the elements in the new array seem like garbage values.

Comment: Yes, but your `newArr` is not necessarily filled in with `SIZE` values. The whole point of the function is to only fill it in with prime values. So by definition it may contain less values than the original array. Also, for similar reason you can't use `i` as the index for `newArray` as not all those indices will be used for the new array.

Comment: But it is filled in with `SIZE` values. The calling code says `int* newArr = cpy(arr, SIZE);` where `int* cpy(int arr[], int size)`

Comment: That doesn't fill it in with `SIZE` values. That only tells the function that the original array is `SIZE`. And then your code allocates a `newArray` of `SIZE`. But allocation is not filling in. This is the code that fills in: `if (isPrime(arr[i])){  *(arr + i) = arr[i];`. And because the assignment is inside an `if` it should be obvious that not all `SIZE` entries in `newArray` will get a value set.

Comment: is `Question 4: 73 2 983 23` the expected output?

Comment: @ganjaam, yes that is. And that makes sense, but that would at least mean that some of the values should get stored in the newArr and the rest be garbage values right?

Comment: @Lauren835, yes. however, it can be handled too. for instance, before copying the primes into newArr, you can count the number of primes in arr. the number of primes should be the size of newArr.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second index into your loop:

```
int* cpy(int arr[], int size){
        int* newArr = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++){
              if (isPrime(arr[i])){
                    *(newArr + j) = arr[i];
                     j++;
               }
         }
         newArr[j] = 0; // add a NULL at the end
         return newArr;
  }
```

If you don`t , you will have an array with uninitialized values left from memory

Example:

Input: 1 3 6 9 13

Output:  1 3 72742729 92652729 13

Reason: 6 and 9 was skiped and a trash value was left.

Comment: The final `newArr[j] = 0;` would have undefined behavior if all values in `arr` are prime. You should allocate an additional entry to avoid this: `int *newArr = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(int));` It unclear how the number of entries in the new array is supposed to be passed back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* cpy(int arr[], int size){
    int* newArr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (isPrime(arr[i])){
            *(arr + i) = arr[i]; // <---------------- ? why you use arr here?
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

try:

```
int* cpy(int arr[], int size){
    int* newArr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    memset(newArr, 0, sizeof(size * sizeof(int)); // <----- initialize newArr
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (isPrime(arr[i])){
            *(newArr + i) = arr[i]; // <--- ? I think you want to use newArr here
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

and maybe you can also add a memset on the newArr:

`memset(newArr, 0, sizeof(size * sizeof(int));`

memset will initialize a certain area of the memory (newArr) with a default value (0), for a certain number of bytes (size * sizeof(int)), so that you won't find 'rubbish' there (rubbish being non initialized values)

Answer (score 0):

Your have undefined behavior because the `cpy` function does not write anything to the destination array: `*(newArr + j) = arr[i];` just copies `arr[i]` to itself.

There is another problem: you only copy some entries, so you should use a separate index for the destination array and change the function prototype to return the number of elements stored there.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return n == 2;
    for (int i = 3;; i += 2) {
        int quo = n / i;
        int rem = n % i;
        if (quo < i)
            return 1;
        if (rem == 0)
            return 0;
    }
}

void printIntArr(int *arr, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int *filter_primes(int arr[], int size, int *nprimes) {
    int *newArr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (isPrime(arr[i])) {
            newArr[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    *nprimes = j;
    return newArr;
}

int main() {
    int arr[SIZE] = { 129, 73, 87, 2, 923, 6743, 983, 23 };
    int n;
    int *newArr = filter_primes(arr, SIZE, &n);
    printf("Question 4: ");
    printIntArr(newArr, n);
    free(newArr);
    return 0;
}
```